# Error implementing __contains__ (in) for a Python class

Tags: python, class, contains

I am trying to implement contains such that it can be used for any of several attributes in my python object. I was able to successfully implement "==" and most of the other comparison operators, but "in" is giving me problems:

```
import operator
class Comparator:
     def __init__(self,fieldName,compareToValue,my_operator):
         self.op = my_operator
         self.field = fieldName
         self.comparedTo = compareToValue
     def __call__(self,row):
         my_row_val = getattr(row,self.field)
         return self.op(my_row_val,self.comparedTo)


class Row:
    class RowItem:
         def __init__(self,name):
              self.name = name
         def __eq__(self,other):
             return Comparator(self.name,other,operator.eq)
         def __contains__(self,other):
             return Comparator(self.name,other,operator.contains)
    val1 = RowItem("val1")
    val2 = RowItem("val2")
    val3 = RowItem("val3")
    val4 = RowItem("val4")
    def __init__(self, val1, val2, val3, val4):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self.val3 = val3
        self.val4 = val4
    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.val1,self.val2,self.val3,self.val4])
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


class MyTable:
    def __init__(self,rows):
        self.rows = rows
    def filter(self,condition):
        for row in self.rows:
            if condition(row):
               yield row

rows = [Row(1,2,3,"hello"),Row(1,2,7,"cat"),Row(1,2,3,"hi"),Row(7,7,7,"foo")]
mytable = MyTable(rows)

# the line below works fine!
print list(mytable.filter(Row.val3 == 7))

# this line below does not work
print list(mytable.filter("h" in Row.val4))
# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

# this line also does not work
print list(mytable.filter(Row.val4 in "hello world"))
# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not instance
```

Comment: `__contains__` is simply not the right tool for this job, abandon that idea.  You need to make a callable to pass to filter .

Comment: Your filter method expects a callable "condition" object. And in fact it tries to call it for every row. However, you are passing a boolean value! When you write '  "h" in row_obj.val4 ' then you are calculating a single boolean value, and it cannot be called.

Comment: Why is it that `Row.val3 == 7` is not a boolean and `"h" in Row.val4` is a boolean?

Comment: Apparently `__eq__` will happily allow you to return any kind of value you like, but `__contains__` will forcefully convert to boolean. The `Comparator` object you return is truthy (as are most object instances), so `"h" in row_obj.val4` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: The problem with the last line is that `RowItem.__contains__` is called when you want to see if something is `in` a `RowItem`, not when you want to see if a `RowItem` is in something. The `TypeError` is being raised by `str.__contains__`, not your `RowItem` class.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: [Why is the return value of `__contains__` coerced to boolean, but that of `__lt__` and the like is not?](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-July/127293.html) It discusses one possible workaround: overloading the `<<` operator instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin for answering this in the comments. The issue was that `in` (the `__contains__()` method) coerces the result to a boolean unlike the other logical comparison operators (`__lt__()`, `__eq__()`, and others).

It seems like the reason for this is mostly backwards compatibility. 
More information here:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-July/127297.html

One way around this is to create a new method (for example, contains_):

try something like this (this is a bad example, because **contains** would work in this code :

```
import operator
class Comparator:
     def __init__(self,fieldName,compareToValue,my_operator):
         self.op = my_operator
         self.field = fieldName
         self.comparedTo = compareToValue
     def __call__(self,row):
         my_row_val = getattr(row,self.field)
         return self.op(my_row_val,self.comparedTo)


class Row:
    class RowItem:
         def __init__(self,name):
              self.name = name
         def __eq__(self,other):
             return Comparator(self.name,other,operator.eq)
         def contains_(self,other):
             return Comparator(self.name,other,operator.contains)
    val1 = RowItem("val1")
    val2 = RowItem("val2")
    val3 = RowItem("val3")
    val4 = RowItem("val4")
    def __init__(self, val1, val2, val3, val4):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self.val3 = val3
        self.val4 = val4
    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.val1,self.val2,self.val3,self.val4])
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

instead of:

```
         def __contains__(self,other):
             return Comparator(self.name,other,operator.contains)
```

Of course, when trying to perform "in", you would need to do something like this:

```
print list(mytable.filter(Row.val4.contains_("h"))) #new way to call in (__contains__)
```

instead of:

```
print list(mytable.filter(Row.val4.__contains__("h"))) #old broken way to call in (__contains__)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For `filter` you have to pass a callable, not a boolean
2. `row_obj.val4` is an instance of the class `RowItem`, and not a string as expected by the `__contains__` method of the `string` class

Comment: How can `Row.val3 == 7` not be a boolean and `"h" in Row.val4` be a boolean though?

Comment: In theory, he could write a __contains__ method that would return a callable that checks containment for any row. However, that is against the protocol: the __contains__ method should return a boolean value.

Comment: because `__eq__` for your `RowItem` returns a `Comparator`, which is callable

Comment: `__contains__` for `RowItem` is also returning a `Comparator`

Comment: You would _like_ it to return a Comparator, but it seems that Python is "helpfully" converting it into a boolean for you.

Comment: in this case you may want to write `"hello world" in Row.val4`?

Comment: `a in b` translates roughly to `b.__contains__(a)`

Comment: ok, actually @Kevin is right, when you use `in`, it's automatically converted to boolean